# Getting one element from each list, random number of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a function to take one number from each list and create possible combinations of the numbers. I don't know how many lists will appear every time... For example:

Getting 4 lists: `x1, x2, x3 and x4`, I need to get output:

`(x1[0], x1[0], x1[0], x1[0]),  (x1[0], x1[0], x1[0], x1[1]),  (x1[0], x1[0], x1[0], x1[2])...` or in  any other format.

I know how to get it from specific amount of lists using `for` loop:

```
for i in range(len(x1)):
    for j in range(len(x2)):
        etc ...
```

but how may I get it when the number of lists is random?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a job for `itertools.product`?

Comment: Have you tried using [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)?

Comment: Have tried right now and it works, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`itertools.product` does exactly that. It takes a variable number of arguments, so we can use `*lists` to unpack our list-of-lists into one argument for each list:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> x1 = ['f', 'g', 't']
>>> x2 = ['a', 'e', 'o']
>>> x3 = ['t', 'd', 'r']
>>> lists = [x1, x2, x3]
>>> list(itertools.product(*lists))
[('f', 'a', 't'), ('f', 'a', 'd'), ('f', 'a', 'r'), ('f', 'e', 't'), ('f', 'e', 'd'), ('f', 'e', 'r'), ('f', 'o', 't'), ('f', 'o', 'd'), ('f', 'o', 'r'), ('g', 'a', 't'), ('g', 'a', 'd'), ('g', 'a', 'r'), ('g', 'e', 't'), ('g', 'e', 'd'), ('g', 'e', 'r'), ('g', 'o', 't'), ('g', 'o', 'd'), ('g', 'o', 'r'), ('t', 'a', 't'), ('t', 'a', 'd'), ('t', 'a', 'r'), ('t', 'e', 't'), ('t', 'e', 'd'), ('t', 'e', 'r'), ('t', 'o', 't'), ('t', 'o', 'd'), ('t', 'o', 'r')]
```